# Manage drop-down menu with NULL ID in update view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

this is the drop-down menu, I use in the insert view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("P1_ID_1", Model.dropDown_1.Select(obj => new SelectListItem() { Text = obj.description, Value = obj.ID.ToString() }), "select")
```

it is not obligatory so it can also be NULL.

When I then recall the view in update mode I use this syntax for the drop-down menus:

```
@Html.DropDownList("P1_ID_1", Model.dropDown_1.Select(obj => new SelectListItem() { Text = obj.description, Value = obj.ID.ToString(), Selected = Model.CIT20.P1_ID_1 == obj.ID }), "select")
```

If the ID is not NULL it works but if the ID is NULL it fails.
How can I do not to make the drop down menu fail when the ID is NULL ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i'm noob, the controller was empty.

```
        var d1 = from m in db.cit20_dropDown_1 orderby m.ID select m;
        model.Cit20_dropDown_1 = d1.ToList();
        var Cit20_dropDown_1 = new SelectList(model.Cit20_dropDown_1.ToList(), "ID", "description");
```

Thanks